# AngularJS and being DRY

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue with AngularJS while trying to maintain the concept of DRY [Don't repeat yourself]. I hope I am doing something wrong and someone can point out my error.

A company sells trucks and cars. **Both items have similar and dissimilar properties. Some are required when adding to inventory for one, while not the other, so it appears I will have to create two forms, one for truck and car**. OK, not a problem. But here is where I am confused.

Both truck and car have a property called transmission, so I would much prefer to create a 'template" to add a transmission type, and thru ng-include embed it in the "Add Truck" and "Add Car" form. But because I am using ng-include, the template by itself is not in scope with the main form and I need to qualify it's ng-model.

If I use this in the transmission template's input : **ng-model="newTruck.Tramission**", the form to add a new truck has it in scope and works fine, but obviously not the car form which I would like to also share this template. So I thought to use this: **ng-model="$parent.Transmission"** so the template can be used by either form, but this does not work.

**The implications for this can cause an unnecessary bloated website, ie StockNumber template, Interior, Exterior Colors template, etc... .**

So, am I correct that I will need to violate DRY and have identical templates like the "Add Transmission" template for every dissimilar product that has such a property, or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit: If I had not made myself clear, transmission is an associated class for car and truck and not a primitive property.**

Comment: 21 views and not a bit of help. This is why I use StackOverflow with intrepediation.

Comment: Lets say angularjs did not exist. How would you do this in a DRY way?

Comment: If I was using ASP.net MVC, since the properties are of the same name, I would just use the name, ie <%=model.Name%> and <%=model.Description>. I would not have to qualify the class because at the top of the ASP.net MVC page the model would be stated, just like at the top of the Add Truck and Add Car form I state TruckCtrl and CarCtrl, thereby leading one to rationalize that '$Parent.' would be sufficient and hold the same purpose as 'model.', but apparently that is not the case.

Comment: how is anyone supposed to help when no code is provided to see what is getting repeated? Post a demo. Likely numerous ways to help resolve issue

Answer (score 3):

This is the kind of scenario for which , I assume, `ng-init` is built into Angularjs. From what you mentioned I am going to assume that you are there are two kinds of objects, but parts of those objects are going to be same (kind of a mixin).

So, you are going to have a class called `Car` and a class called `Truck` but both these contain an object called `transmission` which is what the user will be editing inside that `ng-include`. In order to be editing the same transmission object inside the `ng-include` and making the controller agnostic of the  parent object of `transmission` how about you define a contract?

```
<div ng-controller="CarCtrl">
    <div>{{car.name}}</div>
    <div ng-include="'transmission.html'" >
    </div>
</div>



<div ng-controller="TruckCtrl">
    <div>{{truck.name}}</div>
    <div ng-include="'transmission.html'">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now this is how your `transmission.html` will look like :

```
<div class="transmission" ng-controller="TransmissionCtrl">
<!-- you want to be able to do model.transmission.type in here and be agnostic of whether model is car or truck-->
    {{model.transmission.type}}
</div>
```

Now comes the `ng-init` magic.

Just add `ng-init="model = car"` at the same level as `ng-include` and you are good to go.

```
<div ng-controller="CarCtrl">
    <div>{{car.name}}</div>
    <div ng-init="model = car" ng-include="'transmission.html'" >
    </div>
</div>
```

So now your `TransmissionCtrl` is agnostic of the model whose transmission it is editing. DRY?

Answer (score 0):

The view and controller should not use 'Car' or 'Truck', but more generic 'vehicle'.
Store the possible values for each vehicle type in configuration objects, and reference those when needed.

Handle the differences by having vehicle type attribute.

```
<div ng-show="vehicle.type == 'car'">   {{config.carTransmissionTypes}} </div>
<div ng-show="vehicle.type == 'truck'"> {{config.truckTransmissionTypes}} </div>
```